# The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted (on PROCEDURE)

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, procedure

I have 2 applications running on the server, namely "production applications" and "dev applications". There is no difference between the two applications in addition to their use, the other for developing and the other for users.

There is no problem with the "dev application", but the problem is precisely in the "production application".

The following is one of the problems :
when I tried to update the data, an error appeared :

> "The transaction ended in the trigger. The batch has been aborted"
>   [image]

Even though there is no code difference with the "dev application"

This is my code :

```
    ALTER PROCEDURE  [dbo].[uspFakultas] 

      @FakultasID varchar(50),
      @Dekan varchar(50),
      @KetuaProgram varchar(50),
      @WakilDekan1 nvarchar(50),
      @stat varchar(20)
    AS 
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    if @stat = 'delete' and @FakultasID<>''
        begin
            DELETE FROM [dbo].[MasterFakultas]
                  WHERE [FakultasID] = @FakultasID
        end
    else
        begin   
        if @FakultasID='' 
            begin
                INSERT INTO [dbo].[MasterFakultas]
                           Some field .....
                     VALUES
                           some values.....
            end
        else 
            begin
                UPDATE [dbo].[MasterFakultas]
                   SET some data......

                 WHERE [FakultasID] = @FakultasID
            end
    end;
```

And this is php code

```
$sqlstr=" exec [dbo].[uspfakultas] '$FakultasID','$Dekan','$NomorSK','$KetuaProgram','$WakilDekan1','$stat'";
$hasil=mssql_query( $sqlstr ) or die(mssql_get_last_message());
print $hasil;
```

Anyone can help me ?

Comment: The problem is in the trigger though? Not the SP - so we need to see the trigger code.

Comment: I don't have trigger code

Comment: so, I have to add a trigger.. ok thanks, i'll try it

Comment: No, I'm sure, I don't have any trigger code

Comment: you mean like this right?  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-trigger-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: you can see the error on above, i have add it on question

Comment: ok thanks, I'll be looking for it again.

Comment: There are database level triggers as well as table level triggers, and there are scripts to find them all on SO.

Answer (score 0):

Do any of the tables that you operate on in your stored procedure have any replication on them?

I have seen, in a few applications, replication triggers causing this issue.

Comment: Nothing, but I have database replication.

Comment: can you check and tell me, if the replication has created any trigger on database?

Comment: I have checked it and there were no triggers there